# pCloud Desktop does not save credentials

Tags: cloud, auto-login, pcloud

I am having some trouble with pCloud Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded it from the official website.

I can't make it to save credentials when I turn off the pc. Every time I boot back into ubuntu I have to type the password again.
Is there a way to make it remember the credentials without having to type them every time?

Some time ago I was using Linux Mint and pCloud worked fine, so I think the problem is with Ubuntu, not with the program itself.
It generated in the home directory a `.pcloud` dir, so I tried to open the files there with a text editor but it doesn't work.
I am not a Linux expert, does anybody know how to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: >"I was using Linux Mint and pCloud worked fine"        
       
Just wanted to point out that I had same issue on Linux Mint.  So it's probably not Ubuntu exclusive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged into pCloud website from my browser and that seems to have fixed the issue. The desktop app now is logging in automatically.